# Windows Phone 8 resolution fix

Tags: windows-phone-7, resolution

When im testing WP7.1 application on HTC 8x it has some "blank" space in system tray area. I know that its because of new resolutions, but how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just upgrade your project to Windows Phone 8 and recompile it. If you haven't hard-coded sizes in pixels in your layout, it should automatically fill the extra space.

Comment: Still want to support 7.1 too..So i think ill have to develop 2 branches.. :(

Comment: @0x49D1 Unfortunately, yes. But there's some tricks to easily maintain two versions of a same project: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Maintaining_a_WP7_and_WP8_version_of_a_same_application